# What features for starting astrophotography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, astrophotography, camera-recommendation, lens-recommendation

I'm looking to start astrophotography with my son. I've had some small success with getting bright stars on camera and planets in camera with my phone (sony Xperia 1 ii), but I want to make the jump to a dedicated camera.

I have been looking at the second hand DSLR market, but I have no idea what features I should be looking for in a camera and/or lense for starting out with astrophotography.

What features do I need to look for and why?

Comment: If you have specific questions which aren't answered in the linked duplicate, please either edit this question to include those specific questions or ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: A much better fit for duplicate would be: [What are the features needed in a DSLR for astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90840/15871)

Comment: Also related: [What lens characteristics are important in star photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43114/15871) and [What camera equipment do I need for deep space photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40084/15871) and [What is a decent beginner's camera for astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23193/15871) and [How do I choose a lens to photograph the Milky Way?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48809/15871) and [Am I on the right track for astro photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16634/15871)

Comment: Many people who get seriously into astrophotography don't use DSLRs. They use highly specialized cameras that are designed to produce low-noise images with very low levels of illumination. The best ones are equipped to cool the sensor down to sub-freezing temperatures. (for example: https://www.telescope.com/Orion/Orion-StarShoot-G24-Full-Format-Color-Imaging-Camera/rc/2160/p/132767.uts)

Comment: See also: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/